# My database icon is missing from the right sidebar

Tags: intellij-idea

I was watching a tutorial and the teacher's intelli j has a database icon on right sidebar and mine don't. How can I do the same? Or there's another way to access it?

[image]

Comment: Please attach your idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE.

Answer (score 3):

You may put it via selecting `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Database`. Assigning a shortcut it is also useful. You may assign it in the `Keymap`.

[image: database selection]